# Which Lego Technic sets are officially combinable?

Tags: technic, set-database

Lego sets 42058 Stunt Bike and 42059 Stunt Truck can be combined together to build a bigger truck. We can find official instruction on the LEGO site.

Are there other pairs (or larger groups) of sets like that?

I am particularly interested in Technic sets released in the last couple of years, but it would be great if there were a comprehensive list of such sets or a way we can search them.

Comment: Related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever a LEGO Technic set is officially meant to be combinable with another set, it is mentioned right on the box, as well as in the instruction booklet, and also in the official set description at the Online LEGO Shop. The combined instructions are posted at the LEGO Technic website.

As far as a list, I don't know of any place that has a comprehensive list like that, but I agree it would be very useful. I do know, however, that the two LEGO Technic Pull-Back Racers released each year since 2013 can always be combined with each other with downloadable instructions. Here is the list of the sets:  https://brickset.com/sets/list-15258

Comment: Famous example from this year: you can combine 3 of the anniversary sets (one of them is the Telehandler) to create a modern version of the legendary Car Chassis technic kit from the beginning of Technic.